# When I refresh my website I get a 404. This is with Angular2 and firebase

Tags: typescript, firebase, angular, firebase-security, firebase-hosting

**When I refresh my website I get a 404. This is with Angular2, typescript and firebase.**

I've deployed to firebaseapp with my Angular2 app.

Routes seem to change fine but when I refresh the browser it redirects me to 404 page.

When I refresh locally this doesn't happen.

Am I missing any route settings or Firebase settings?

**This is my firebase.json file:**

```
 {
   "firebase": "test",
   "public": "src",
   "ignore": [
     "firebase.json",
     "**/.*",
     "**/node_modules/**"
   ]
 }
```

Comment: Let me know if anyone needs to see the angular2 routes

Comment: I get a 404 redirect to a firebase 404 page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 : 404 error occur when i refresh through Browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284988/angular-2-404-error-occur-when-i-refresh-through-browser)

Comment: i dont get 404 when page is refreshed when hosted in firebase! Are u using the latest Angular dependancies ?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

For Firebase Hosting the documentation on redirects and rewrites is here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/url-redirects-rewrites.html

From there:

> Use a rewrite when you want to show the same content for multiple URLs. Rewrites are particularly useful with pattern matching, as you can accept any URL that matches the pattern and let the client-side code decide what to display.

You're likely looking for the first rewrite sample on that page:

```
"rewrites": [ {
  "source": "**",
  "destination": "/index.html"
} ]
```

This is an instruction for the web server to serve `/index.html` for any incoming request, no matter what the path is.

Comment: @AngularM or anyone who understand how to solve the problem will they please provide the working example of removing the procedure of `#` from the URL ?

Comment: the pound sign (hashtag) can be removed using $locationProvider as seen here https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

Comment: You missed the starting " at "rewrites". Thx for the answer!

Comment: you have to add above code in firebase.json, so it will looke like this->  {
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist\\Login",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [{
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "/index.html"
      }]
  }
}

Comment: {
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/myproject",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [ {
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "/index.html"
    } ]
  }
}

Comment: Tried this solution on Angular 12 and works better than the # useHash solution

Answer (score 24):

Expanding on the accepted answer I wanted to show that the rewrites rules go *inside* of the hosting rules. in the firebase.json

```
"hosting": {
  "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
   } ]
}
```

Firebase also has an [updated docs page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites) where the above example is from.

Also, I was thrown off by the hash (#) question around this. I found that doesn't apply to the new Angular. Making these small changes in the firebase.json, rebuilding, publishing to firebase, and then doing a refresh page with clear-cache immediately resolved my 404 issue with no workarounds required for hashes in the URL.

Answer (score 20):

I think that you use the default mode of Angular2 routing (i.e. `HTML5LocationStrategy`). In this case, you need some configuration on your webserver to make load the `index.html` (your entry point file) for each URLs corresponding to each routes.

If you want to switch to the HashBang approach, you need to use this configuration:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {LocationStrategy, Location, HashLocationStrategy } from 'angular2/router'; 

import {MyApp} from './myapp';

bootstrap(MyApp, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
]);
```

In this case, when you refresh the page, it will be displayed again.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: I dont want to hash approach

Comment: So you need to configure your server side to serve the `index.html` file for each route you defined...

Comment: how i do that for firebase hosting? and with angular2?

Comment: I think this link could help you: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-12-12-building-reviewable-with-firebase.html ;-) There is nothing to do within your Angular2 application...

Answer (score 18):

I had the same issue on production.
The following steps helped me to fix the problem.
You have to add in your root module next:

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})]
```

and it will swich to HashLocationStrategy.
[Angular documentatation](https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles)

Hope it will help someone !!

Comment: it did help me :)

Comment: But, one problem. When I am refreshing in any path other than path '', it is redirecting to path ''. Like, on abc.xyz/#/dashboard, If I am refreshing it is going to abc.xyz/#/. Any Idea? I checked header, footer, app.component ngOnInit & Constructor no where I am calling to path and removing hash solving problem in localhost