# Angular2 unable to load boot.js

Tags: angular

I can't get pass boot.js file when i run directly from: `file:///C:/wamp/www/ngProject/index.html`  or from wamp : `http://localhost/ngproject/`

In develop mode it works with `npm-start`, but shouldn't it work with WAMP or just by running Index.html?

This is my system.js

```
  <script>
  System.config({
    packages: {        
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
  System.import('app/boot')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

**When starting from wamp** - Error: Unable to load script http://localhost/app/boot.js Error loading http://localhost/app/boot.js
**When starting Index.html** - Error: Unable to load script file:///app/boot.js
    Error loading file:///app/boot.js

Comment: have you tried checking the console for errors..??

Comment: yes i edited the post with the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you always need a http server to run an Angular application.

Take a look at this question. There are some pretty solid answers on why a http server is needed.

[Why do I need a HTTP-server to run Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34580772/why-do-i-need-a-http-server-to-run-angular-2)

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your path to boot.js. When starting from wamp - Error: Unable to load script http://localhost/app/boot.js

`Error loading http://localhost/app/boot.js`

The path here seems to be wrong,because your js file is located

@ `http://localhost/ngProject/app/boot.js`

Something like this might hep you

**For wamp server try this**

```
 System.config({
            baseURL: 'ngProject'
        });

System.import('app/boot')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

Comment: The path is `C:\wamp\www\ngProject\app\boot.js`

Comment: Yes,The localhost is pointed to the C:\wamp\www\ folder right..?

Comment: Cris, Angular has to be hosted on the "server" so try to think of paths as "whateverURL"/path/to/file instead of how it actually is locally. I say that because often server setups MASK the local file system, which is often the case in Angular2 seeds. For example, my seed converts: /GIT/project/src/client/app to: localhost

Answer (score 0):

So when you use npm-start there is likely a server setup for your project for your seed. This will have all the config settings for the server that runs in your seed package.

If you used the [angular2-seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed) which I love but can be slightly complicated with its options, the settings are in: tools/config/seed-config.ts

What this does is MAP to your root folder to load files.

Wamp by default maps `localhost` to `c:\www` but you actually want it to map to `c:\www\ngProject`

Think about it like this,

When you load `/ngProject/index.html`
It says, "Ok, I need to load boot.js which is located at `/app/boot.js`"

but it's really at `/ngProject/app/boot.js` and it fails

You can either change your system to load from /ngProject in all your configs, or what I reccomend is adjust your wamp settings.

Instructions from [this SO Answer:](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/84069)

For wamp 2.5 on Windows, use a text editor, e.g. notepad++ to edit c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\httpd.conf

1. Change DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www" to DocumentRoot "c:/my/new/path"
   (Note slash direction). This will change the location where files
   are served from (~Line 230).
2. Change  to
        (Note slash direction). This applies
       permissions from the old directory to the new one (~Line 252).

Another thing, is MANY of the seed's also have a "Production" build which will automatically convert to a relative/base root path structure. That is something I'd check too..

Comment: I tried changing `DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/ngProject"
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/ngProject">` and even `DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/ngProject/app" <Directory "c:/wamp/www/ngProject">` but has no effect. Even my php projects work as usual from www folder.

Comment: I read about other ways (like Angular2 WebpackStarter or Angular2-Seed , that can turn all js into 1 and minify it, but i couldn't figure out how to make it work...