# Angular 2, routing URL path to route in the app

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 2 app hosted on S3. The routing file looks like this.

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: 'checkout', component: CheckoutComponent },
  { path: 'thankyou', component: ThankyouComponent },
  { path: 'lander', component: LanderComponent },
  { path: '', component: LanderComponent }
];
```

If the user enters `www.example.com/checkout` I would like it to take them to the `checkout` route on the app. I figured it would just do this, but S3 is giving me the error No Such Key. Is there a way to do this in Angular 2, or is it something I need to set in S3?  I think the problem is S3 is going to the `example.com` bucket and then expecting a folder `checkout`. How would I have it not do that and just the app along with whatever route is specified after the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES, { useHash: true })
```

Comment: thanks. won't this cause a hash to show up in the URL though? ideally i would just like the url path

Answer (score 0):

RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES)

{ useHash: true } is an option. When you add it, the URL uses Hashes.
Without it, no hashes.

Answer (score 0):

#### Angular routing strategies

Add you routes `APP_ROUTES` to the router using [`RouterModule.forRoot`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule#forRoot):

```
forRoot(routes: Routes, config?: ExtraOptions)
```

and pass the config as [`ExtraOptions`](https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#useHash) with `useHash: true`:

> When true, enable the location strategy that uses the URL fragment instead of the history API.

Following table compares the different effects:

| useHash | routing strategy used | e.g. routed as | e.g. supposed effect |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `false` | *PathLocationStrategy* (without the hash) | `/checkout` | would go directly to S3 bucket and key `checkout` |
| `true` | *HashLocationStrategy* (with the hash symbol) | `#/checkout` | would stay inside your Angular app |

#### Angular routing to bypass S3

To achieve this you could create the router as follows:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES, { useHash: true })
```

This question deals with the same issue: [Angular 4 routing --prod mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48144303/angular-4-routing-prod-mode)

#### See also

Related questions:

- [Angular static Base URl and routing with useHash=True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52416210/angular-static-base-url-and-routing-with-usehash-true)
- [PathLocationStrategy vs HashLocationStrategy in web apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34703343/pathlocationstrategy-vs-hashlocationstrategy-in-web-apps/58362590#58362590)