# Angular 4 routing --prod mode

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, angular-cli, angular4-router

I've recently built an app using angular 4 in production flag `--prod`.

It gave me some static files in the dist folder and after that I've uploaded the dist files in AWS S3 bucket. It all went fine until I clicked refresh. While clicking refresh on other routes like /page1 or /page2 it is showing '404 not found' no such key error.

Am I doing anything wrong here? I know the problem exists because there is only one file (index.html) in the dist folder. But what about other routes?

How could I make other pages available even after refreshing the page.

Comment: which server use? apache or nginx?

Comment: am using nginx in my instance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NGINX and Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38991541/nginx-and-angular-2)

Answer (score 0):

You must be configured NGINX for angular 2 routing.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39009388/5165692)

Check Answer this.

Hope so it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do define default routing in your app-route file and add the second parameter in RouterModule like that

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

it's working for me