# Angular static Base URl and routing with useHash=True

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular 6, I want my app to have a static base URL for the purpose of reverse proxy configuration.

In my `index.html` I set base Url

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>APM</title>
  <base href="/my-base">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <pm-root></pm-root>
</body>
</html>
```

In my `app.module.ts` I have the routing table configured

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './home/welcome.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    WelcomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: "welcome", component: WelcomeComponent },
      { path: "", redirectTo: "welcome", pathMatch: "full" },
      { path: "**", redirectTo: "welcome", pathMatch: "full" }
    ], { useHash: true })
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

After I launch the application I noticed the URL is `http://localhost:4200/my-base#/welcome`, there is a # after `my-base`.

If I change the code in routing to have `useHash: false` then the # is after my base URL and becomes `http://localhost:4200/my-base/welcome#/welcome`

I could not find lots of information what exact the meaning of `useHash: false`, what is the consequence?

Comment: A detailed explanation can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58362590/3298390

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Simple summary

The main difference is whether Server is easy to implement the redirect mechanism

`useHash: true` is easy to implement than `useHash: false`

---

## Principle

when you set `useHash: false`, it's using **PathLocationStrategy**, It's using `HTML5 pushstate` that requires server support

When you enter the Url to Browser

```
localhost:4200/my-base/welcome/
```

The server needs to redirect **localhost:4200/my-base/welcome/** to your index.html

---

`useHash: true`, it's using **HashLocationStrategy**

you need to add `#` after your base-href('my-base'), the URL is

```
localhost:4200/my-base/#/welcome/
```

The server directly makes a request to **localhost:4200/my-base/** to your index.html, It's easy to implement in server side.

---

**Reference**

Angular How to work with Server Side(IIS, Nginx) using PathLocationStrategy(useHash: false)

- [Deploy an Angular Application to IIS](https://indepth.dev/posts/1239/deploy-an-angular-application-to-iis)
- [Nginx and Angular URL routing](http://andredublin.github.io/javascript/2014/08/18/nginx-and-angularjs-url-routing.html)