# Angular routing after ng build

Tags: node.js, angularjs, localhost, hosting

I'm getting an error: "Cannot GET /main" when I access this address: "http://localhost/main"
I attach pictures of my code after ng build

I moved the created folder (named client) after ng build to the server

I hope you can help me
Thank you [my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phiXR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your express server is not redirecting to your index.html.

You can also use the routing with hash.

More details can be found here

[Angular static Base URl and routing with useHash=True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52416210/angular-static-base-url-and-routing-with-usehash-true)

Answer (score 0):

Could you share a picture of the `main.component.ts` please. The error occurs because it cannot find `Maincomponent`

[image]

I reckon the error comes because you have mispelt the main.components export.