# Angular 11 throws 404 error when hitting url directly instead of navigating through app

Tags: angular

I am trying to learn Angular and I have created a simple web application. I build the application using

`ng build --prod`

and has deployed it in the tomcat server.

The application gives 404 error whenever I try to hit any url directly other than the home url.
(The application is completely frontend and there is no backend involved)

Home page url - http://54.160.203.76:8080/passgen/  - this loads perfectly fine.

Other Url - http://54.160.203.76:8080/passgen/feedback - this gives 404 error.

```
//routes array

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: PassgenComponent },
  { path: 'passphrase', component: PassphraseComponent },
  { path: 'strength', component: PassStrengthComponent },
  { path: 'feedback', component: FeedbackComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' },
];


// code snippet to use the routes

 <div class="nav-links">
    <div routerLink="" (click)="navSlide()">Password</div>
    <div routerLink="strength" (click)="navSlide()">PassStrength</div>
    <div routerLink="passphrase" (click)="navSlide()">Passphrase</div>
    <div routerLink="feedback" (click)="navSlide()">Feedback</div>
  </div>


//index html base href

 <base href="./"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Add `useHash: true` in the `routerModule` [See Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52417120/11719787)

Comment: Try adding `feedback` route inside a child route array of `passgen`

Comment: @Sameer I went through the explanation and did understood the problem; but using `#`  in a production application will not look weird?

Comment: @MirentafazAli I did  added it in child route but after adding it stopped working completely and wont even change using the app


`const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PassgenComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'passphrase', component: PassphraseComponent },
      { path: 'strength', component: PassStrengthComponent },
      { path: 'feedback', component: FeedbackComponent },
    ],
  },

  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' },
];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to configure your tomcat to request index.html on every route change.

For this, add RewriteValve in /opt/tomcat/latest/conf/context.xml (path may or may not be different in your case).

In your project folder, create **WEB-INF** folder, then add a file **rewrite.config** in WEB-INF with below content:-

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(bmp|css|gif|htc|html?|ico|jpe?g|js|pdf|png|swf|txt|xml|svg|eot|woff|woff2|ttf|map)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [L]
```

After this, restart your tomcat server.

Comment: For nginx it is something like this: try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;

Answer (score 0):

Please use the routing like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: PassgenComponent,
    children: [
      {
       path: 'feedback', // child route path
       component: FeedbackComponent, // child route component that the router renders
      }
    ]
   },       
   { path: 'passphrase', component: PassphraseComponent },
   { path: 'strength', component: PassStrengthComponent },     
   { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }      
]
```

Answer (score 0):

For Apache I created a `.htaccess` file in the root directory of the domain and added below content, if anyone lookin for.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```