# Can anyone provide a simple example of how to perform routing without a hash in the url?

Tags: angular-dart

I have been search for days for an answer to this but documentation is very limited. I want to be able to type a url for my app without using the # symbol. can anyone provide an example of this? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To enable routes with `#`, add this to Angular app-level providers

```
Provider<LocationStrategy>(
    LocationStrategy,
    useClass: HashLocationStrategy)
```

without `#` is the default anyway.
The server needs to support HTML5 PushState for that to work.

See also [PathLocationStrategy vs HashLocationStrategy in web apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34703343/pathlocationstrategy-vs-hashlocationstrategy-in-web-apps)