# Routing URL contains an Fragment (#)

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Im working on an angular application (Version 6) which is hosted on an AWS s3 Bucket.

There is a little `#` in my app url routing which wont break my routing or isnt a problem at all. Anyway I tried to get rid of the `#` with no success so far.

A little Example:

`http://localhost:4200/#/Login` should be `http://localhost:4200/Login`

Which is the best way to get rid of the `#` ?

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

 // ----- Import of all the Components
 ...

export const routes: Routes = [

  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'Login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'signup', component: signupComponent },
  { path: 'Password', component: PasswordResetComponent, data: {title: 'Passwort Reset'} },
  { path: 'password', component: PasswordResetComponent, data: {title: 'Passwort Reset'} },
  { path: 'confirmation', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'Error', component: ErrorPageComponent, data: {title: 'ERROR'} },

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);

@NgModule({
   imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
   exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

In the **app.module.ts** I just import the `AppRoutingModule`

Comment: @JohanRin You are Right, i will build the app tomorrow to check if its also working on the S3 Bucket. If so, i will mark it as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your app-routing.module look for this line

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash : true}) //<= Change this boolean to false
```

There are currently 2 routing strategies
Take a look at this separate related answer to further understand the differences

[PathLocationStrategy vs HashLocationStrategy in web apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34703343/pathlocationstrategy-vs-hashlocationstrategy-in-web-apps)

Comment: This is exactly the option I was looking to turn on; thank you