# Angular 2: 404 error occur when I refresh through the browser

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have stored my single-page application in my server within a folder named as "myapp". I have changed the URL in the base to [http://example.com/myapp/`](http://example.com/myapp/%60).

My project has two pages. So I implement Angular 2 routing. I set the default page as login. When I type `http://example.com/myapp/` in my browser it will redirect automatically to `http://example.com/myapp/login`. But if refresh that page I get a `404` error, saying that `http://example.com/myapp/login` is not found.

But if I run my project using the lite server everything is working. In this case the base URL in index.html will be `"/"`. How do fix it?

Comment: Currently, I worked with the angular 9 application and deployed it on an IIS server with a web.config file and when we refresh the page it loads the angular app correctly. I think this is not an issue with the angular application.

But when I deployed the code to the Ubuntu server application gives the 404 not found error because we did not configure the URL rewrite rules. After adding the.htaccess file for rewrite the URL's It works on refresh.

Comment: I had the same problem in production, in development was fine. This answer fixed this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39103122/12603542, with `useHash: true`, Ill have to just figure out how to get rid of `/#/`

Comment: In my case SEO folks don't want # to be there in URL, for IIS without hash it works by creating a web.config but anyone have any idea how to fix this in apache without hash location strategy?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

In fact, it's normal that you have a 404 error when refreshing your application since the actual address within the browser is updating (and without # / hashbang approach). By default, HTML5 history is used for reusing in Angular2.

To fix the 404 error, you need to update your server to serve the `index.html` file for each route path you defined.

If you want to switch to the HashBang approach, you need to use this configuration:

```js
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';

import {MyApp} from './myapp';

bootstrap(MyApp, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
]);
```

In this case, when you refresh the page, it will be displayed again (but you will have a `#` in your address).

This link could help you as well: [When I refresh my website I get a 404. This is with Angular2 and firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34415725/when-i-refresh-my-website-i-get-a-404-this-is-with-angular2-and-firebase/).

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks a lot. However, is there any disadvantage in using the HashBang approach?, I mean in terms of SEO or anything else?

Comment: What if we don't want to use HashLocationStrategy but PathLocationStrategy?

Comment: @Ben As Thierry mentioned, "if you want not having a 404 error, you need to update your server to serve the index.html file for each route path you defined." Detailed ways for each server software are in [Angular Wiki about working with `html5Mode`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode), or refer to the linke provided by Thierry for Firebase configuration.

Comment: answer below is for update for angular2 final version

Comment: Did you find this solution in Angular 4?

Comment: @BhaveshHirpara Most answers in this version also works for Angular 4.

Comment: Franklin Yu's answer should actually be the accepted answer. Thierry Templier's answer just says put back the # to get rid of the problem, which isn't an answer or use the link provided with assumes the poster is using firebase, which the poster probably is not. The wiki provided by Franklin answers the questions, with a side note, for Apache, you can add the same config in an .htaccess file.

Comment: This answer would be more complete if you included how to update the server to serve the index.html file for each route path defined (PathLocationStrategy). Thanks for what you've contributed thus far though.

Comment: @KyleVassella This answer wants you to change from `PathLocationStrategy` to `HashLocationStrategy`. The solution of sticking to path location is explained in other answers.

Comment: Can you please provide the solution for Angular 7. I am getting 404 on page refresh in angular 7 with spring boot (REST service). both are running on different ports.

Comment: Hash technique works, But I think we can simple add .htaccess to get this fixed with the below code RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

Answer (score 294):

#### Update for **Angular 2 final** version

In app.module.ts:

- Add imports:

  ```
    import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
  ```
- And in NgModule provider, add:

  ```
    {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
  ```

***Example*** (app.module.ts):

```
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule  } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

---

#### Alternative

Use RouterModule.forRoot with the {useHash: true} argument.

***Example:***(from [angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#browser-url-styles))

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
...

const routes: Routes = [//routes in here];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Answers may be rearranged according to popularity, so relative positioning will not be preserved. Please provide a link to the other answer in your answer.

Comment: Does this work in IE? I run angular2 app on Apache (Windows Server) and I get 404 error page.

Comment: @Asaf Hananel , will this work for RC-6 ?

Comment: @CleanCrispCode yes, it should work, if not let me know

Comment: This does work for me. Thank you. But is there a way to lose the #?

Comment: Yes this works for me too. But I am using auth0 for authentication and I have to provide allowed urls. when I refresh page which adds a hash now, then login it wont accept the url. What is a suggestion to fix this or remove the hashtags when the page is refreshed?

Comment: @Sparked Any solution you have found?

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot I'm afraid not. I ended up living with the #, in the end.

Comment: @Sparked can we change # to any #name or something?

Comment: Adding providers first solution of this answer(providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],) DID WORK!! thanks a TON! /\!

Comment: There is a way to not use the hash (#) in the link?? The solution worked fine but now i have a link like: "test/app/#/login"

Comment: @PriNcee Sure, there is. See [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284988/angular-2-404-error-occur-when-i-refresh-through-browser/40833154#40833154). (Actually I prefer the one without the hash; it feels less hacky.)

Comment: Does this method works on Angular 5? because I am also getting error while refreshing page

Comment: Yes this works for me too. But I am using auth0 for authentication and I have to provide allowed urls. when I refresh page which adds a hash now, then login it wont accept the url. What is a suggestion to fix this or remove the hashtags when the page is refreshed?

Comment: @HRPATEL Read through all the answers below and you will find a solution.

Comment: hi Thanks for help but it raised another problem
I am using this at login page now my first time login does not succeed but second time wit same credentials it succeeds????

Comment: What would be value of const routes: Routes = [//routes in here]; ?

Comment: I was facing the same issue but it was working fine in local but giving 404 in the PROD. Adding the above-mentioned `providers` it worked like a charm, thanks @AsafHananel

Answer (score 187):

For people (like me) who really want `PathLocationStrategy` (i.e. html5Mode) instead of `HashLocationStrategy`, see *[How to: Configure your server to work with html5Mode](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode)* from a third-party wiki:

> When you have html5Mode enabled, the `#` character will no longer be used in your URLs. The `#` symbol is useful because it requires no server side configuration. Without `#`, the URL looks much nicer, but it also requires server side rewrites.

Here I only copy three examples from the wiki, in case the Wiki get lost. Other examples can be found by searching keyword "URL rewrite" (e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34415725/when-i-refresh-my-website-i-get-a-404-this-is-with-angular2-and-firebase/34418131#34418131) for Firebase).

#### Apache (file name should be .htaccess in root directory )

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my-app

    DocumentRoot /path/to/app

    <Directory /path/to/app>
        RewriteEngine on

        # Don't rewrite files or directories
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]

        # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow HTML5 state links
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

[Documentation for rewrite module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

#### nginx

```
server {
    server_name my-app;

    root /path/to/app;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

[Documentation for `try_files`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files)

#### IIS  (file name should be web.config in root directory )

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules> 
      <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: This topic relates to Angular 2(4) - your response is AngularJS related

Comment: @Playnox Everything mentioned here also applies to Angular 2 to 4. (Actually I didn't begin using Angular since 2.) You may have jumped to the conclusion by the link to Angular-UI wiki, where code sample is AngularJS.

Comment: And I get downvoted because of the false accusation. Well, at least there is some feedback...

Comment: @FranklinYu Have you seen any configurations for WebLogic servers? Haven't had any luck.

Comment: @overboard182 Sorry, I don't have any experience of WebLogic. Some online Q&A (like [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/177795/url-rewrite-in-weblogic-11g)) suggest that WebLogic does not support URL Rewriting, so you have to do it either in front of WebLogic (reverse proxy) or behind WebLogic (let WebLogic proxy request to another application or Servlet).

Comment: Hi, sorry I encoutered this error and when I put your apache config I got those errors  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <, what I miss in my config?

Comment: @AdouaniRiadh Is there line number for this error?

Comment: Morning; I found a solution. it's very similair as yours configuration
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48076301/apache-angular-oauth-redirection-resource-not-found?answertab=votes#tab-top
Thanks

Comment: I'm not having any luck using the IIS one for my server.  When I refresh from a route it goes back to the root.

Comment: This answer in my view is the correct one, it preserves the HTML5 features of angular and makes the server function correctly.

Comment: Great It works well for nginx. For me this is also the correct answer.

Comment: @HimanshuDhirajMishra Nginx? Did you mean Apache?

Comment: @FranklinYu, yes ! I did changes in .htaccesss

Comment: You can also use .htaccess that works for me as below 


Options +FollowSymLinks

<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</ifModule>

Comment: my problem in nginx I put   root /path/to/app; inside location thank you

Comment: didn't work for me

Answer (score 38):

I had the same problem. My Angular application is running on a Windows server.

I solved this problem by making a **web.config** file in the **root** directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: @DaneVinson [The Angular Wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions) is even earlier. Anyway he should probably give someone credit.

Comment: In case of WebApi service (For the Server). Notice, that the angular application not placed in the same folder of WebApi. You can create another folder, and change the href in index.html

Answer (score 32):

Perhaps you can do it while registering your `root` with `RouterModule`. You can pass a second object with property `useHash:true` like the below:

```
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule  } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { ROUTES }   from './app.routes';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES ,{ useHash: true }),],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: This is the simplest approach if you just want to get something working quickly. However, anuglar.io recommends against it "Stick with the default unless you have a compelling reason to resort to hash routes." https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: just adding { useHash: true } solved my problem thanks !

Answer (score 8):

For people reading this that use Angular 2 rc4 or later, it appears LocationStrategy has been moved from router to common. You'll have to import it from there.

Also note the curly brackets around the 'provide' line.

**main.ts**

```
// Imports for loading & configuring the in-memory web api
import { XHRBackend } from '@angular/http';

// The usual bootstrapping imports
import { bootstrap }      from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent }         from './app.component';
import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from './app.routes';
import { Location, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
]);
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're running Angular 2 through ASP.NET Core 1 in Visual Studio 2015, you might find this solution from Jürgen Gutsch helpful. He describes it in [a blog post](http://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2016/08/08/setup-angular2-typescript-aspnetcore-in-visualstudio.html). It was the best solution for me. Place the C# code provided below in your Startup.cs public void Configure() just before app.UseStaticFiles();

```
app.Use( async ( context, next ) => {
    await next();

    if( context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !Path.HasExtension( context.Request.Path.Value ) ) {
        context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
        await next();
    }
});
```