# angular2(2.0.0-beta.3) routing by url not working

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Currently I am playing with angular2 routing. Every thing is working as expected but manually typing the route url in browser is not working.

The current code I am using

**app.ts**

```
    import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
    import {Route,RouteConfig,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from "angular2/router";
import {DashboardComponent} from "./dashboard/dashboard.component";
import {UsersComponent} from "./user/users.component";


    @Component({
        selector:'app',
        template:`
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <nav>
          <a [routerLink]="['Dashboard']">Dashboard</a>
          <a [routerLink]="['Users']">Users</a>
        </nav>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        `,
        directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
        providers:[ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
    })


    @RouteConfig([
        new Route({
            path:'/dashboard',
            component:DashboardComponent,
            name:'Dashboard',
            useAsDefault:true
        }),
        new Route({
            path:'/users',
            component:UsersComponent,
            name:'Users'

        })

    ])
    export class App{

    }
```

**boot.ts**

```
    import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {App} from "./app";
import {HashLocationStrategy} from "angular2/router";
import {LocationStrategy} from "angular2/router";
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from "angular2/router";
import {provide} from "angular2/core";


bootstrap(App, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
]);
```

Routing using the anchor tags is working perfectly fine but when I manually types the same url(**http://localhost:3000/users  or  http://localhost:3000/dashboard**) in browser and hit enter it says

```
Cannot GET /users   

or 

Cannot GET /dashboard
```

Please suggest me how can I detect the browser's location URL changes to match the path segment (/users or /dashboard) and activate the corresponding Component(or UsersComponent or DashboardComponent) and display its view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2.0 router not working on reloading the browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser)

Comment: My question is not (Angular 2.0 router not working on reloading the browser)  it is (after defining the angular route,  It is not working by directly typing in browser though it is working with anchor tag )

Comment: both the question are same @Jorin

Comment: To your update. The URL is invalid when you use `HashLocationStrategy`. That's what `HashLocationStrategy` and the default `PathLocationStrategy` are about, they work with different URL patterns to point to routes.

Comment: have you set <base href="/">?

Comment: @pardeep reloading comes only after loading it ..... I am asking It is not being  loaded your all are telling it all about reloading which dont work simply on HTML5 and needs some server based route mapping to index.html ... LoL

Comment: @hahn yes i had set the <base href="/">

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer means I had to use PathLocationStrategy to work with my type of url  http://localhost:3000/dashboard  also I tried changing the url to  http://localhost:3000/#/dashboard for my above updated code but it is also not working

Comment: Yes, and if you use `PathLocationStrategy` you need to use a server that supports it. I don't know if `http://localhost:3000/#/dashboard` is a valid route for `HashLocationStrategy`. Load your index.html and navigate to the route in question and then check what URL Angular produces.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks.....  finnally I resolved it  :P

Comment: Would be interesting to know how?

Comment: Just by moving the HashLocationStrategy from boot.ts to app.ts

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/41030337/1090745 to learn how to use HashLocationStrategy

Answer (score 3):

It's something normal since by default, HTML5 history is used for routing with Angular2. You need a server configuration to redirect all your routes to the HTML entry file.

You could have a look at this answer:

- [Angular 2 : 404 error occur when i refresh through Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284988/angular-2-404-error-occur-when-i-refresh-through-browser/35285068#35285068)

Comment: hey Thierry Templier thanks for your reply... I followed the link you supplied and modified by boot.ts as below
`
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {App} from "./app";
import {HashLocationStrategy} from "angular2/router";
import {LocationStrategy} from "angular2/router";
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from "angular2/router";
import {provide} from "angular2/core";


bootstrap(App, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
]);`

But it did not help me

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figure out a solution . Solution was to use HashLocationStrategy like below

**app.ts**

```
 import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
    import {Route,RouteConfig,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from "angular2/router";
import {HashLocationStrategy} from "angular2/router";
import {LocationStrategy} from "angular2/router";
import {provide} from "angular2/core";

import {DashboardComponent} from "./dashboard/dashboard.component";
import {UsersComponent} from "./user/users.component";


    @Component({
        selector:'app',
        template:`
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <nav>
          <a [routerLink]="['Dashboard']">Dashboard</a>
          <a [routerLink]="['Users']">Users</a>
        </nav>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        `,
        directives:[ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers:[HeroService,ROUTER_PROVIDERS,provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})]
    })


    @RouteConfig([
        new Route({
            path:'/dashboard',
            component:DashboardComponent,
            name:'Dashboard',
            useAsDefault:true
        }),
        new Route({
            path:'/users',
            component:UsersComponent,
            name:'Users'

        })

    ])
    export class App{

    }
```

**boot.ts**

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {App} from "./app";
bootstrap(App);
```

Thank you