# Angular JS 2 route with sails js

Tags: sails.js, angular

I'm trying to set up a sails js app with Angularjs 2 in front.
I Want to use the angularJS system routing and no sails js system.

How can I disable the sails route and let angular control them ?
This is my app.component.ts where I declare the route /account

```
import {View, Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {AccountComponent}   from './account.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@RouteConfig ([
    {path: '/account', name: 'Account', component: AccountComponent}
])


export class AppComponent {

}
```

If I remove the route in config/routes.js, this doesn't work.
I try to disable some options in config.blueprint.js but nothing good.

I want to use Angular route to have an SPA and don't reload pages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it's normal that you have an error when trying to access route directly without having a configuration on the server. In fact the actual address of a route is updating (and without # / hashbang approach) by Angular2 without any interaction with the server when using a route. The path doesn't exist on the server. If you load the HTML entry point file, everything will work fine. The only problem is when you try to access directly a route from its path...

By default, HTML5 history is used by Angular2. If you want not having this problem, you need to update your server to serve the `index.html` file for each route path you defined.

If you want to switch to the HashBang approach, you need to use this configuration:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import {LocationStrategy, Location, HashLocationStrategy } from 'angular2/router'; 

import {MyApp} from './myapp';

bootstrap(MyApp, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
]);
```

In this case, when you refresh the page or access directly the page, it will be displayed again (but you will have a `#` in your address).

This link could help you as well:

- [Angular 2 : 404 error occur when i refresh through Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284988/angular-2-404-error-occur-when-i-refresh-through-browser/35285068#35285068)

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 1):

I have to return "/" for all routes in config/routes.js and let angular to display others view.

Comment: I faced a similar situation and I managed to serve an Angular 12 app from SailsJS as a static resource by overriding all front end routes with a GET to the app bundle. Thank you for the hint.