# How to use angular 2 slash routes with node express?

Tags: javascript, express, angular

I have some routes defined in my App component:

```
@routeConfig([
{ 
    path:'login', 
    name: 'Login', 
    component: Login
}}
```

And a very basic node express loader:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('app'));
app.use('/node_modules', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/'));

app.get('/home', function(req, res, next) {
  next();
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Serverlistening on port 3000!');
});
```

My issue is that going to '/login'/ is intercepted by node express and it says 'cannot get /login'. I want Angular2 to handle it. It worked fine in node lite server but not in express.

How can I configure express to ignore these routes and allow Angular to handle them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to configure your route this way:

```
@routeConfig([
  { 
    path:'/login', // <---------- 
    name: 'Login', 
    component: Login
  }
])
```

**Edit**

If you hit the request directly, you need to have something to return the content of the `index.html` file for the request into your Express application.

This must be done for each route defined in Angular2. Otherwise you will have 404 errors.

See this question for more details:

- [Angular 2 : 404 error occur when i refresh through Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284988/angular-2-404-error-occur-when-i-refresh-through-browser/35285068#35285068)

Comment: Nop that's not working. I'm hitting the URL directly from the browser (not clicking on any links). The issue is that Express get's the request first, then can't find a match so throws an error.

Comment: If you hit the request directly, you need to have something to return the content of the `index.html` file for the request into your Express application...

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284988/angular-2-404-error-occur-when-i-refresh-through-browser/35285068#35285068

Comment: yes thanks I actually just figured this out as well lol :-/ Do you want to post an answer, explaining that all that is needed, is a catch all * route in node express and to serve the index.html?