# Angular2 without hash in the url

Tags: html, angular, angular2-routing

Now, my website's url looks like this because I'm using the approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284988/angular-2-404-error-occur-when-i-refresh-through-browser)

http://localhost:4200/#/cadastro

Is it possible to remove the hash in the url and not get the 404 error?

**EDIT: Router Module added**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'cadastro', component: CadastroNoivosComponent },
    { path: '**', component: HomeComponent }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use [PathLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles) as describe [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles) you can remove the hash in the URL.

But getting rid of 404 error needs some server side tweak. A quick and easy way is to configure your server to load the home page when any URL of the form `http://yourhost/*` is requested.

Comment: is it intented to have both links to same page?

Comment: i dont wanth to use useHash. Then how to i solve this issue

Answer (score 37):

If you are using Angular final, the reasons to the hash could be:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(yourRoutesHere, { useHash: true })
```

So by removing that could help.

```
RouterModule.forRoot(yourRoutesHere)
```

Alternatively if you in your providers (in NgModule) have used:

```
{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
```

just remove that.

EDIT, if you need LocationStrategy, try changing `HashLocationStrategy` to `PathLocationStrategy`:

```
{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy}
```

**More about LocationStrategy [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/LocationStrategy-class.html)**

Now that I have seen your routes as well regarding your 404 issue, you could try changing the following

```
{ path: '**', component: HomeComponent }
```

to:

```
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

**More about routing [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)**

Also check that in your `index.html` you have set the basehref like so:

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: It's already like this "RouterModule.forRoot(yourRoutesHere)". And if I remove the "{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}" I will get the 404 error when I reload the page.

Comment: Updated answer, try with `PathLocationStrategy`

Comment: no lucky with the `PathLocationStrategy`, still getting the 404 error when reloading the page :(

Comment: Okay, then it seems there could be something going on with your routes. Could you add your routing module to your question?

Comment: Routing module added

Comment: In my case It is working on local(ng serve) environment but on the production(ng builld --aot --prod) it is not working.

Comment: @EmilioWeba, I have the same issue, did you found any solutions

Comment: rewrite the url in nginx or .htaccess file

Answer (score 4):

Create a .htaccess file Paste the following Code And Upload on your prod Server.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Comment: This is actually a very great answer. It helped me a lot. I did not use however the first rule. Is it necessary?

Comment: it's depends upon your language you are using! Above code was for Angular 9