# Angular 2 routing issue - 404 error on refresh or reload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I am facing an issue related to angular routing. All pages work fine but if page is reload or refreshed it give 404 error.I am using path location strategy. I have searched a lot but found thing except hash location strategy.I have tried Hash location strategy but is adds # in url (Like webiste.com/home#contact) but i want url without #.

I need experts guide as i am stuck after searching 3 4 days

Thanks in advance

Comment: you are trying on localhost or some server ? if on server than you have to redirect your page to requested page , otherwise hash location exist as u know

Comment: Check this link May be it is helpful.
[Angular2 without hash in URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41662326/angular2-without-hash-in-the-url)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what server you are using, you need to configure your routing to point to index.html always.

Of course you need to set `<base href="/">` in `<head>` of your `index.html`

If you refresh url `site.com/myPage`, server will try to get resource with name myPage, in your case will return 404.

**WAMP settings**

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
```

**IIS settings**

```
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: i am using window server as my application is in asp.net mvc

Comment: For IIS see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614072/how-do-i-configure-iis-for-url-rewriting-an-angularjs-application-in-html5-mode

Comment: @JánHalaša gave a good example. I will edit my answer for IIS config.

Comment: Thanks @JánHalaša  :-)

Comment: Thanks @MarioPetrovic :-)

Comment: Cheers. Glad it helped.