# Angular 4 - All routes not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I have an Angular app working properly at `localhost:4200` by using `ng serve`; The node server is at `localhost:3000`.

When i do  `ng build` a bundle file is being created and served properly at `localhost:3000` because of `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'path/to/dist')));` but the routes which worked at `localhost:4200/user/id` is giving an error at `localhost:3000/user/id` stating it `Cannot GET /user/id`.

Any ideas what is causing the problem? I have included `<base href="/">` in the `index.html` file.

Comment: what Routing Location Strategy are you using? Just double checking whether you did not miss "/#/" as in localhost:3000/#/user/id

Comment: Hey, The routes work at ```localhost:3000/#/user/id```, But i'm not understanding what is happening here.

Comment: Because you're not using history mode but hashmode https://stackoverflow.com/a/41662473/2880747

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your *Routing Location Strategy* is causing the issue.

Notes straight from Google:
[Angular 4 documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles)

URL depending on your chosen strategy:
PathLocationStrategy: localhost:3000/user/id
HashLocationStrategy: localhost:3000/#/user/id

You can modify **useHash** property in your **app module** to switch between the two:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })  // .../#/user/id
  ], ...
});
```

That said, if you mismatch the URLs, your GET should fail.

Comment: Yep, this works but how to use ```PathLocationStrategy``` as showing users as ```http://localhost:3000/index.html#/user/id``` is not friendly.

Comment: In your project find "RouterModule.forRoot" call. Modify it to "RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: false })" . Confirm whether you can then access  "localhost:3000/user/id"  or not

Comment: No, i'm not able to access it after making `useHash: false`