# PathLocationStrategy works only locally

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I have problem with hash, on my working project when I build it, on test project all work correctly. I already read this questions in google:
[Angular2 without hash in the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41662326/angular2-without-hash-in-the-url)
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/url-routing-without-hash/81140
but I didn't find answer.
When I add

```
{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
```

All work correctly, but with hash. When I add

```
{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy}
```

It work only on local version. But working version don't work http://joxi.ru/n2YLOaMijK7Pam
How can I remove this hash http://joxi.ru/RmzBzxDTWbjeQm what would it work on my build project ?

app.module.ts

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {MaterialModule} from '../shared/mat.module';
import {UserModule} from './user/user.module';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {ToolbarComponent} from './toolbar/toolbar.component';
import {HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';
import { TestingRComponent } from './testing-r/testing-r.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ToolbarComponent,
    TestingRComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MaterialModule,
    UserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
   import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {Route, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {UserComponent} from './user/user.component';
import {TestingRComponent} from './testing-r/testing-r.component';

const routes: Route[] = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {
    path: 'auth',
    component: UserComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'testing',
    component: TestingRComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

user-routing.module.ts

```
  import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {Route, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {RegistrationComponent} from './registration/registration.component';
import {UserComponent} from './user.component';
import {LoginComponent} from './login/login.component';
import {TestingComponent} from './dynamic-fields/testing/testing.component';

const routes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: 'auth', component: UserComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'registration',
        component: RegistrationComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'testing',
        component: TestingComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class UserRoutingModule {
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`PathLocationStrategy` uses `HTML5 pushState` which depends on the `<base>` HTML tag. You need to tell the browser what will be prefixed to the requested path. Remember to add it in your app:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Here You can read more about [routing in Angular](https://angular.io/guide/router)

One more important thing is to route (**on the server side**) every Angular route to base path specified in `index.html`. For example, this is how it is done in `nodeJS`:

```
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {req, res});
});
```

or `Apache`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Otherwise, when your customer will reach for example `www.example.com/path/someThing` your server will be looking for `index.html` file in the `/var/www/example.com/path/someThing/` instead of `/var/www/example.com/`

Comment: I use angular cli and it add it automatically http://joxi.ru/BA0QR0JuBjvWWr

Comment: Isn't is a problem with your remote server? Give me a sec, I will update my answer.

Comment: I read this https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles and added PathLocationStrategy as I wrote

Comment: I updated my answer with some `server-side` advice. Check it now.

Comment: Where I should add it ? I have my project here http://joxi.ru/vAWWyKqhk43XZA and have two directory client (angular) and server (node + express) http://joxi.ru/BA0QR0JuBj17or I should add it to my server directory ? I think no, because i can have project without node, only angular and have same problem.

Comment: All routes, for UI, should point to your `client` directory. I added `node` code as an example. Same rule works for any different server app: `apache`, `tomcat` etc. etc.

Comment: Hey Maciej, where to add this in node.js -- > app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {req, res});
});

Comment: @SuchetaShrivastava take a look at this example: https://github.com/maciejtreder/ng-toolkit/blob/master/application/server.ts

Answer (score 1):

You was right, my problem was with hosting https://www.beget.com/ru, I found this solution https://geekbrains.ru/topics/3055 and i should add in my file 
.htaccess this code:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

And now it work. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Added your code to my reply, to make it more complementary.

Answer (score 0):

in your routing add `pathMatch` like this:

```
const routes: Route[] = [
        {
          path: 'auth', 
          component: UserComponent,
          pathMatch : 'prefix',
          children: [
            {
              path: 'registration',
              component: RegistrationComponent,
              pathMatch : 'full'
            },
            {
              path: 'login',
              component: LoginComponent
              pathMatch : 'full'
            },
            {
              path: 'testing',
              component: TestingComponent
              pathMatch : 'full'
            }
          ]
        }
      ];
```

notice that the parent `pathMatch` is set to `prefix`.