# Angular 4 Routing not working after hosting to web server

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-route-segment

[Routing Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBETs.png)
I have created 6 routing app for my web app. It is working normally on localhost, but when I try to load a URL after hosting server it finds 404 error. 
For Example;
when I tried to access an URL using my localhost

localost:port/split   it works perfectly

but after I hosting to server it finds 404 using the same path;

example.com/split --> it finds 404

I have uploaded the screen shot of routing component here. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What is your `base-href` in `index.html`? Also, what type of server are you hosting it on?

Comment: May be try ``example.com:port/split`` ? In case you are running app using ``ng serve`` otherwise look into base-href in Index.html

Comment: please post your router code

Comment: in base-href="/". Can I replace the base-href="/" with my domain name that is base-href="/domain name"

Comment: check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48742496/pathlocationstrategy-works-only-locally/48742571#48742571