# Problems with webpack build, using angular-cli

Tags: node.js, angular, nginx, webpack, angular-cli

I am using `angular-cli` with built-in `webpack` and encounter the following problem: if I use `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000` everything works fine, but when I try to build the app (no matter developer mode or production) with `ng build` and then put it into my `nginx`, not a single route works and every attempt of browser to download image, which is used on start page, ends with 404 error. What am I doing wrong? Googled a ton of stuff and nothing seems to be a solution.

Some additional info:

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.21
node: 6.9.4
os: win32 x64
```

Comment: are you sure you have nginx configured correctly?

Comment: have you tried to serve a minimal `index.html` file with nginx?

Comment: @shusson it seems like nginx is trying to find corresponding files inside the folder of an app, but instead there are only `index.html` and `main.bundle.js`, because that's how `webpack` builds an app. Is there any solution for this available?

Comment: an `index.html` file is all nginx needs. You should look up how Single Page Applications work. Maybe try using a different server like pythons SimpleHttpServer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for everyone who encounters this problem, after some research I found this:

1) To solve problem with styles not loading properly, add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to each of your components `@Component()` decorator, this way it's going to bundle styles properly. More info here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#loading-styles

2) Make sure all your images are stored inside `assets` folder. If you store them in some other folder like `images`, just put that `images` folder inside `assets`

3) And for information about paths not working on page reload, have a look at this question and read some information about strategies: [Angular 2 : 404 error occur when i refresh through Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284988/angular-2-404-error-occur-when-i-refresh-through-browser)
Also this link has config examples https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode