# node with angular 2, getting get 404 error when you type in the route in url bar

Tags: node.js, angular, routes

When using node with angular 2, there is odd thing that happens that i would like to be fix. Basically if I were to type in the route in the url such as `localhost:3000/about` in the browser url bar. I get Cannot GET /home. However when click on the nav bar that i made that has the same link /about. it work just fine. I know it a problem with node because originally, I was using dev-server this error didn't happen with angular 2.

angular 2 routes

```
    const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'private', component: PrivateComponent},
  { path: 'title', component: TitleComponent},
  { path: 'shop', component: WelcomeComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent}
];
```

navbar

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-dark bg-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar">
      &#9776;
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="exCollapsingNavbar">
      <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['/home']">Vietnam Films</a>

      <div class="nav navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" [routerLink]="['/home']">
          Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
        </a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link"  [routerLink]="['/about']">About</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link"  [routerLink]="['/film']">Film News</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link"  [routerLink]="['/shop']"  *ngIf="auth.loggedIn()">Shop</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" [routerLink]="['/checkout']"  *ngIf="auth.loggedIn()" >Checkout</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" (click)="auth.login()" *ngIf="!auth.loggedIn()">Login</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" (click)="auth.logout()" *ngIf="auth.loggedIn()" >Logout</a>
      </div>

      <div class="nav navbar-nav  float-xs-right">
        <db-cart-menu  *ngIf="auth.loggedIn()" ></db-cart-menu>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

node backend

```
    var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var jwt = require('express-jwt');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon')
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var cors = require('cors');
var config = require('./config');

    // models for the mongodb
    var Director = require('./models/directors');
    var Film =  require('./models/films');
    var Product = require('./models/products');
    var User = require('./models/users');



    var app = express();

    // Create an HTTP service.
http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
console.log("listen on 3000");
// Create an HTTPS service identical to the HTTP service.
https.createServer(options, app).listen(8000);

// links the node server to the webpage
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../')));
app.use(cors());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(cookieParser());

//the rest is the rest api routes
```

Comment: If his answer does not help you I suspect this has to do with location. Read this answer which causes this problem when they refresh. I think it is related. You can also solve this with using something like handlebars for the index page only. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35285068/2218253

Comment: @wuno note that if you choose to go with HashLocationStrategy it won't be a aot friendly code "Almost all Angular projects should use the default HTML5 style. It produces URLs that are easier for users to understand. And it preserves the option to do server-side rendering later."

Comment: Sure. Handlebars might make your life easier then. If you use handlebars and only make an index file then route through it, it has been known to solve this problem. When using a node server. For what reason I do not know. Been there done that though. It was a pain in the ass so I feel your pain Jason.

Comment: how do I do the handlebars method to fix this exactly?

Answer (score 3):

Since `/about` is not defined as a route in your server-side, either you need to define them 1 by 1 or you need to add something like

```
app.get('/*',  function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname }); 
});
```

To redirect every refresh to angulars routing.

Comment: so i added the  app.get('/*',  function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile('../index.html', { root: __dirname });
}); and I got the forbidden error when typing in the url.

Comment: @JasonTran Might be a proxy issue but is the url correct tho? It might vary depending on your folder structure. Can you check if the it can find index.html from the network tab?

Comment: @JasonTran I see that you have a `'../'` when providing your index.html you might need to add it again. Something like `{ root: path.join(__dirname, '../Xyour_folder_nameX') })`

Comment: the url is correct as i click the nav bar and the url match the typed url. network tab? I think I route it to the index.html as i kept my server.js file in a folder call server so it should just be one directory back.

Comment: @JasonTran you get the forbidden error after you click on navbar after adding this code?

Comment: yeah and refreshing the page. I made sure that it connected to the index.html file as I tried to mess with the location and it gave me a different error where it said that it couldn't be found. So location isn't the issue.

Comment: @JasonTran I don't understand. This code will only kick in when you refresh the page not when you click on a url : / On a url click angular's routing will handle the request. Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: it doesn't work if I either refresh or type it in the url bar. It work fine when i'm using localhost:3000 and it goes to the page then I click on the nav link that i made.

Comment: @JasonTran ah ok. Can you screenshot your folder directory?

Comment: app.get('/*',  function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('/../index.html',  { root: path.join(__dirname, '../vietnam-film.ver7') }));
});
so tried adding this to my node server and it got rid of the forbidden error but I'm getting TypeError: Path must be a string. { directory name/} how do I put a screenshot on this site?

Comment: @JasonTran `{ root: path.join(__dirname, '../vietnam-film.ver7') }` is not a string. If you want to use `path.resolve` then all your args must be string https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths

Comment: found the answer to the problem.  I added the code from this blog. Thanks for the help though. http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/07/26/angularjs-enable-html5-mode-page-refresh-without-404-errors-in-nodejs-and-iis