# refresh page angular 2 router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have the following web with angular 2 routing (using vs 2015 as my IDE)
[image]

however, whenever i refresh the page, i get this:
[image]

Therefore, whenever i want to hard refresh my page, i have to go to the error page first then i need to enter the following url:
http://localhost:57831/index.html

Is there any solution so whenever i hard refresh, it always go to http://localhost:57831/index.html instead of http://localhost:57831/index.html/search?

thanks

Comment: you need to handle routes at server side as well, so that all routes go to your default page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the answer from here:
[Angular 2 : 404 error occur when i refresh through Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284988/angular-2-404-error-occur-when-i-refresh-through-browser)

in app.module.ts:

Add imports:

```
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
```

And in NgMoudle provider, add:

```
{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides that you should try to redirect all 404 request inside your VC2015 webserver to `index.html`. If you have done that, there are two solutions for your problem.

1. Somehow find a way to change the `web.conf` file of your VC2015 application. There you should find a `httpRuntime` entry

Change it to allow the `:`, by removing the `:` entry:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,&amp;,\,?"/>
</system.web>
```

Perhaps this file is located here:

```
%userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config\web.conf
```

2. Do not use the `:` inside your URL, use a dash (`-`) or what ever is not illegal in the comma separated list above (I'd say go for this), there is a reason those characters are considered illegal: