# Angular 4 - Nginx / Refresh shows bad page

Tags: angular, nginx

I have an Angular 4 application deploy on a remote server with Nginx, and accessible with this address: `http://xx.xx.xx.xx/app`. The app works well, I can navigate in my website but when I refresh one page, for example `http://xx.xx.xx.xx/app/page1`, it displays the index.html page of nginx.

Nginx's pages are located in `/usr/share/nginx/html`, and my app's pages are located in `/var/www/app`.

**nginx.conf**

```
    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;                                                */

        location /app {
            root /var/www;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
```

It seems that the line `root /var/www` is not taken into account during a refresh.

I heard something about a bug with try_files, and it seems that I need to add a rewrite somewhere. Thanks for help.

Comment: try with something like this: location ~ ^/app/(.*)$ instead of /app . This ensures that it is matching on any subpages not only /app

Comment: Did you try to change it to `root /var/www/app;` or `try_files $uri $uri/ /app/index.html;`?

Comment: @eesdil Thanks for suggestion but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @PierreDuc Your second suggestion doesn't work. But the first is more interesting. The refresh works well now, but when I go to my website, I am redirect on my app directly, and I don't want that. So I tried to write only `root /var/www;` but the behaviour come back as before...

Comment: You should change to `location /app/` (the extra slash). And I guess you can disregard my first comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add this in your AppModule:

```
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
    // ...
    providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
    // ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Well... That pretty weird, the URL is little bit impact due to the `/#/` but it seems to be invisible for the user. Could you explain how does it works? Thanks

Comment: You can find more explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284988/angular-2-404-error-occur-when-i-refresh-through-browser