# angular2, 404 response on prod

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a little Angular2 app, i have created 2 components, 'main' and 'dashboard'
I have created this button to access the dashboard page:
`<button md-raised-button class="md-primary" [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">Dashboard</button>` 

When i deploy locally with 'ng-serve' i can access the page without any problem directly:
[image]
But when i try the same in production i get a 404:
[image]

Accessing the dashboard page via the button link does not give me any problem, in production or development env
I have in my 'app.module.ts' the folllowing routes set:
`const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'table',      component: MainComponent },
  { path: '**',      component: MainComponent }
];`

In the imports then i configure the router like so:
`RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)`

And in development environment this works just fine, all code is committed and updated, i made sure i run the same code, like 5 times

Comment: That's because your back-end doesn't have a route handler for /dashboard

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284988/angular-2-404-error-occur-when-i-refresh-through-browser, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 : 404 error occur when i refresh through Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284988/angular-2-404-error-occur-when-i-refresh-through-browser)