# Angular 4 route not working

Tags: angular, angular-routing

In a Angular 4 I cant get my route to work

When targeting the URL localhost:8088, I get redirected to localhost:8088/maps, and page displays, but when directly targeting localhost:8088/maps I get a 404 page not found.

What I need is to be able to write the URL directly i.e. localhost:8088/maps

I have this route file:

```
import {Routes} from '@angular/router'
import {EventsListComponent} from './events/events-list.component'
import {EventDetailsComponent} from './events/event-details/event-details.component'
import {CreateEventComponent} from './events/create-event.component'
import {Error404Component} from './errors/404.components'
import {EventRouteActivator} from './events/event-details/event-route-activator.service'
import {EventListResolver} from './events/event-list-resolver.service'
import {MapDetailComponent} from './map/map-detail.component'


export const appRoutes:Routes = [

{path: 'events/new', component: CreateEventComponent, canDeactivate: ['CanDeactivateCreatedEvent']}, 
{path: 'events', component: EventsListComponent, resolve: {events:EventListResolver}},
{path: 'events/:id', component: EventDetailsComponent, canActivate: [EventRouteActivator]},  
{path: 'maps', component:MapDetailComponent},    
{path: '404', component: Error404Component},  
{path: '', redirectTo: '/maps', pathMatch: 'full'}
]
```

And this app_module.ts

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router'
import {EventsAppComponent} from './events-app.component'
import {EventsListComponent} from './events/events-list.component'
import {EventThumbnailComponent} from './events/event-thumbnail.component'
import {NavBarComponent} from './nav/navbar.component'
import {EventService} from './events/shared/event.service'
import {ToastrService} from './common/toastr.service'
import {EventDetailsComponent} from './events/event-details/event-details.component'
import {appRoutes} from './routes'
import {CreateEventComponent} from './events/create-event.component'
import {Error404Component} from './errors/404.components'
import {EventRouteActivator} from './events/event-details/event-route-activator.service'
import {EventListResolver} from './events/event-list-resolver.service'
import {MapDetailComponent} from './map/map-detail.component'
//import { HubService } from 'ngx-signalr-hubservice';

@NgModule({
    imports:[
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
    ],
    declarations: [
        EventsAppComponent,
        EventsListComponent,
        EventThumbnailComponent,
        EventDetailsComponent,
        CreateEventComponent,
        NavBarComponent,
        MapDetailComponent,
        Error404Component
    ],
    providers: [
        EventService, 
        ToastrService,
        EventRouteActivator,
        EventListResolver,
        //HubService,
        {
            provide: 'CanDeactivateCreatedEvent', 
            useValue: checkDirtyState
        }
    ],
    bootstrap: [EventsAppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}

function checkDirtyState(component:CreateEventComponent){
    if(component.isDirty)
        return window.confirm('You have not saved this event, do you really whant to cancel?')
    return true
    }
```

And this component

```
import { Component  } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
    template: `
      <h1>Map</h1>

    `
  })
  export class MapDetailComponent { 

  }
```

Comment: Does this happen when you run your app using `ng serve`?

Comment: are you setting base href?  as `<base href="/">` in your index.html?

Comment: This question is being asked every other day. Read https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2: 404 error occur when I refresh through the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284988/angular-2-404-error-occur-when-i-refresh-through-the-browser)

Comment: im using ng serve, and I have set the base href

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser

Comment: The other routes I have in the app works, with typing full url, and with refresh

Comment: Then try posting a complete, minimal example reproducing the problem. Doing it will force you to remove all the irrelevant stuff from your code, and you will probably find what causes the trouble by doing so.

Comment: Are you using IIS to host your app ? If yes, I'll give you proper web.config to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to type localhost:8088/#/maps