# page refresh is giving 404 in angular5 with springboot application

Tags: spring-boot, angular2-routing, angular5

I have a web service running in springboot on port 8080. when I hit below url it works fine:

http://localhost:8080/app , i redirect the url to below:

http://localhost:8080/myHome/home

now when i refresh the page I am getting 404

below is the content of my index.html:

```
  <base href="/myHome">
```

package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build --dev --deploy-url=\"/app/\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "protractor"
},
```

I had tried using LocationStrategy mentioned in

[Angular 2: 404 error occur when I refresh through the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284988/angular-2-404-error-occur-when-i-refresh-through-the-browser) , but its not working for me.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem in spring boot 2. I have added resources resolver location as static directory and if not matched with any file then load index.html

```java
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addResourceHandler("/**/*")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver() {
                    @Override
                    protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath, Resource location) throws IOException {
                        Resource requestedResource = location.createRelative(resourcePath);
                        return requestedResource.exists() && requestedResource.isReadable() ? requestedResource : new ClassPathResource("/static/index.html");
                    }
                });



}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add { useHash:true } to your routerModule, it worked for me :

imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash:true})]

Answer (score 1):

It error occur cause by spring check resource /myHome/home in but there not found

resource location is /app so you can fix -

```
1) Use hashRouting in angular application
```

or

```
2) Redirect to '/' in springboot aplication when requesting came from another url /**
```

Comment: @Configuration
    public class StaticResourceConfiguration
    extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler(new String[]{"/**"}).addResourceLocations(new String[]{"file:resource/static/"});
        }

        public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
        }
    }

Comment: i tried second option no luck,still getting 404,hash routing too not working

Comment: can you tell me where is you angualrbuild location in spring boot application ?

Comment: doing build of angular application using pom.xml:

<executions>
     <execution>
      <id>install node and npm</id>
      <goals>
       <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
      </goals>
     </execution>
.......,its a monolithic application basically

Comment: You can create a resource folder in spring project and put angualr build  and registry.addResourceHandler(new String[]{"/**"}).addResourceLocations(new String[]{"file:resource/"});

Comment: it worked after using href as ./ and hashbang solution both

Answer (score 1):

This was the solution I found which works: This is in `Kotlin` though. But not hard to change between.

https://github.com/emmapatterson/webflux-kotlin-angular/blob/master/README.md

Hope this helps!
The main code is:

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono

private const val INDEX_FILE_PATH = "/index.html"

@Configuration
internal class StaticContentConfiguration(): WebFilter {

    override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
        val path = exchange.request.uri.path
        if (pathMatchesWebAppResource(path)) {
            return redirectToWebApp(exchange, chain)
        }
        return chain.filter(exchange)
    }
    
    private fun redirectToWebApp(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain) = 
    chain.filter(exchange.mutate()
        .request(exchange.request.mutate().path(INDEX_FILE_PATH).build())
        .build())

    private fun pathMatchesWebAppResource(path: String) =
        !path.startsWith("/api") && path.matches("[^\\\\.]*".toRegex())
}
```