# Angular 2 Routing - Visual studio 2017, getting HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found when refreshing the url in browser

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017, angular2-routing

I have below code which is working fine in all browsers upon launching the application except while refreshing the page, immediately I'm getting HTTP 404-Not Found Issue. In angular, don't know the exact reason and solution.

Following are my components in my application:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
templateUrl: './main.html',
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

**main.html**

```
<div>
<nav>
    <ul class=" nav nav-pills">
        <li routerLinkActive="active"> <a 
 routerLink="/checkifc">checkifc</a></li>
        <li routerLinkActive="active"><a 
 routerLink="checkmaterial">checkmaterial</a>
        <li routerLinkActive="active"><a 
 routerLink="checkcosts">checkcosts</a>
    </ul>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

 </nav>
</div>
```

**app.routes.ts**

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CheckifcComponent } from './checkifc/checkifc.component';
import { CheckmaterialComponent } from 
'./checkmaterial/checkmaterial.component';
import { CheckcostsComponent } from './checkcosts/checkcosts.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
{ path: 'checkifc', component: CheckifcComponent },
{ path: 'checkmaterial', component: CheckmaterialComponent },
{ path: 'checkcosts', component: CheckcostsComponent },
//{ path: '', redirectTo: '/checkifc', pathMatch: 'full' }];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { routing } from './app.routes';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CheckifcComponent } from './checkifc/checkifc.component';
import { CheckmaterialComponent} from 
 './checkmaterial/checkmaterial.component';
 import { CheckcostsComponent } from './checkcosts/checkcosts.component';
 import{ ifcobjecttypeComponent} from './ifcobjectType.component'

 @NgModule({
imports: [BrowserModule, routing , FormsModule, HttpModule,],
declarations: [AppComponent, CheckifcComponent, CheckmaterialComponent, 
 CheckcostsComponent, ifcobjecttypeComponent ],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]})
 export class AppModule { }
```

following are the components where routing is implemented for

**checkifc.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Ifc } from './ifc';
import { BimService } from './bimifc.service';

@Component({
selector: 'checkifc',
templateUrl: './checkifc.html',
providers: [BimService]})

//implementing the class OnInit
export class CheckifcComponent implements OnInit {
ifcprops: Ifc[];}
```

**checkifc.html**

**checkcosts.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Costs } from './costs';
import { BimService } from './bimcosts.service';

@Component({
selector: 'checkcosts',
templateUrl: './checkcosts.html',
providers: [BimService]})

 export class CheckcostsComponent implements OnInit {
checkCost: Costs[];}
```

**checkmaterial.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Material } from './material';
import { BimService } from './bim.service';

 @Component({
selector: 'checkmaterial',
templateUrl: './checkmaterial.html',
providers: [BimService]})

export class CheckmaterialComponent implements OnInit {
AmtofMaterial: Material[];}
```

I am successfully able to debug the application and navigate between the components by loading respective components & HTML pages but HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found is displaying while I am refreshing the page or URL.

Implemented angular2 in Visualstudio 2017.

Also, from the blogs, I found some solution like add rewrite rules in web.config file. there is No fix to my issue even after adding rewrite rules.

Your inputs are most appreciable!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can some experts please help me in resolving the routing issue that I am facing in the project.

Comment: It worked with Hashbang approach,  as you need to update your server to serve the index.html file for each route path you defined.

Comment: for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284988/angular-2-404-error-occur-when-i-refresh-through-the-browser