# How can I remove "#" without getting an error on refreshing the page in Ionic

Tags: html, angular, url, ionic3

I am building an Ionic PWA, in which I have implemented the Deep linking.

```
 IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {}, {
            links: [
                { component: FeaturedPage, name: 'FeaturedPage', segment: ':title' },
                { component: HomePage, name: 'HomePage', segment: ':title' },
                { component: LatestPage, name: 'LatestPage', segment: ':title' },
                { component: TopPage, name: 'TopPage', segment: ':title' },
                { component: TrendingPage, name: 'TrendingPage', segment: ':title' },
                { component: ListPage, name: 'ListPage', segment: ':title' },
                { component: ItemDetailsPage, name: 'ItemDetailsPage', segment: 'Categories/:category' }
            ]
        }),
```

By default, it is generating an URL which contains "#". 
[image]

As per the requirement, I had to remove the "#" so I did research and found that, with the help of following I can remove the "#" from the URL.

```
import { LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy },
```

I got success in results. Now the URL does not contain "#"
[image]

However, when I am refreshing this page, then I am getting an error
[image]

I know that, in order to overcome this type of error, there is the need of putting "#" in the URL, but now I do not want to have "#" nor I want the error after refreshing the page, Is there anybody, who can let me know, how to get rid of this?

Comment: I think this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284988/angular-2-404-error-occur-when-i-refresh-through-the-browser

Comment: Which server are you using to serve your application? If it's webpack-dev-server then look at `devServer.historyApiFallback` option

Comment: @yurzui Right now, I am testing it on Localhost, but will use Apache later.

Comment: See also https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

Comment: @yurzui So I need to configure it on Apache and to do so, I need to rewrite the rule for .htaccess file in the root of the Apache server. Is there any configuration that I will need to do in my project ? How can I get rid of this problem on localhost too?

Comment: `Which server are you using to serve your application?` What are you using for localhost?

Comment: I am using Ionic and by using command `ionic serve`, it runs on 8100 port.

Comment: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1263

Comment: I have done all of them, but issue is still there