# Error refresh page Angular 404 on tomcat 9

Tags: angular, tomcat8

I tried to deploy an agular app on tomcat 9, when i refresh index page work as expected but when refresh on deep-link i get blank page.

I put into webapps/mynameApp/WEB-INF/rewrite.config  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(bmp|css|gif|htc|html?|ico|jpe?g|js|pdf|png|swf|txt|xml|svg|eot|woff|woff2|ttf|map)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [L]` and into context.xml `<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve"/>`

Answer (score 0):

By default angular is a static web, and wont refresh a deep link.

Try implementing this:
https://angular.io/guide/router

This is a duplicate, but I cant mark it as one, yet.
[Angular 2: 404 error occur when I refresh through the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284988/angular-2-404-error-occur-when-i-refresh-through-the-browser)

Here is the code.

Hope it helps.