# redirect to angular pwa in special page in url

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I have an Angular PWA in a subdomain.
I want to redirect from another site to my angular PWA in a special page `http://app.amyar24.com/category?categoryId=55`, but it throws `404 not found`.

How can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: if you paste the url directly onto your browser, does it work as expected ?

Comment: reply Stavm, No

Comment: that probably means your web server isn't serving angular's `index.html` for every sub domain request. you need to [configure your server to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284988/angular-2-404-error-occur-when-i-refresh-through-the-browser/40833154#40833154). OR bypas it all by [using hash in your routing](https://angular.io/guide/router#hashlocationstrategy) module.

Comment: How did you set the scope in your web manifest? Your service worker is able to process all requests within its scope. Have a look here (https://dev.to/paco_ita/install-a-pwa-on-the-user-s-device-step-2-27pa) for more details about the web manifest or here (https://dev.to/paco_ita/service-workers-and-caching-strategies-explained-step-3-m4f) for service workers and caching strategies. There is also a step by step tutorial for Angular PWAs: https://dev.to/paco_ita/create-progressive-web-apps-with-angular-workbox-pwa-builder-step-4-27d#angular