# How to remove # from URL and 404 reload issue in angular build and nodejs application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I have Angular9 and nodejs application.
I am doing `ng build --prod` for production build and putting that build file inside nodejs public folder and now i am able to access the page perfectly.

> but my problem is in URL i want to remove #. Currentlly i am getting
>   as
>
> http://localhost:8080/#/about
>
> http://localhost:8080/#/admin/create/blog

I user some technique to over come this like i use

1. `{useHash: false}`
2. `PathLocationStrategy` : **using this i did angular build and put that build folder in Nodejs Public folder. And in url # is not showing. But when i tried to reload that it is showing 404 not found error.**

I know there will be some extra things need to be added in Nodejs code. But i am not sure how to do this. I check lots of solutions but not able to fix this

**I want URL not to append # and if i refresh it should not throw any 404 error. can anyone guide me how to resolve this?**

**Project structure:**

[image]

**NodeJs code**
**index.js**

```
const express = require('express')
require('./db/mongoose')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const path = require("path")
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080

let blogRouter = require('./routes/blogRouter');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public/dist/blog-ui')))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: 'true' }))
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "50mb" }))
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-token, authorization");
    res.header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "x-token, authorization");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, POST, DELETE, GET, OPTION");
    next();
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on ${port}... `)
});

app.get('/*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname)));

app.use('/api/v1/blog', blogRouter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one npm package, which is using browser history to load the pages. which is fixing my above issue.

Npm Package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-history-api-fallback

**What i followed in my code:**

**Angular App:**

1. Removed HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy and { useHash: true } from my code. I mean not adding any code which is use for resolving reload issue and which was appending # in URL. I removed this related code.
2. build: ng build --prod
3. copy the dist folder to nodejs public folder

**Node and Express Js project change:**

i just changed in index.js file.

1. install above npm package : `npm i connect-history-api-fallback --save`
2. Did code change in index.js. below code i have added in index.js

**What i changed in Index.js**

```
const history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');
const staticFileMiddleware = express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public/dist/blog-ui'));
app.use(staticFileMiddleware);
app.use(history({
    disableDotRule: true,
    verbose: true
}));
app.use(staticFileMiddleware);
```

**Index.js full code**

```
const express = require('express')
require('./db/mongoose')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const path = require("path")
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080
const history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

let blogRouter = require('./routes/blogRouter');

const staticFileMiddleware = express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public/dist/blog-ui'));
app.use(staticFileMiddleware);
app.use(history({
    disableDotRule: true,
    verbose: true
}));
app.use(staticFileMiddleware);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: 'true' }))
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "50mb" }))
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, x-token, authorization");
    res.header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "x-token, authorization");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, POST, DELETE, GET, OPTION");
    next();
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on ${port}... `)
});

app.get('/*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname)));

app.use('/api/v1/blog', blogRouter);
```

Answer (score 0):

to avoid 404 redirecting issue in refresh we can use `HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy`

In `app.module.ts`:

Add imports:

`import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common'`;

And in NgModule provider, add:

```
{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
```

Example (`app.module.ts`):

```
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule  } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

for more :[Angular 2: 404 error occur when I refresh through the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284988/angular-2-404-error-occur-when-i-refresh-through-the-browser)

Comment: But `#` is coming in URL. I want to avoid both # and 404 issue

Comment: try adding  `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })`  in imports

Comment: `{ useHash: true }` this also same case

Answer (score 0):

to avoid the 404 redirecting issues in refresh we can use the following imports in app.module.ts

```
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
```

Try like this, your 404 error will be resolved.