# Angular Security Policy Heroku

Tags: angular, heroku, content-security-policy

I have Angular application with routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomePageComponent },
  { path: 'rome-routing', component: SomeRoutingComponent},
  { path: 'other-routing', component: OtherRoutingComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

and have config in my index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
          content="default-src*; 'self' style-src 'unsafe-inline' script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://mySpringBootApp.herokuapp.com https://myAngularApp.herokuapp.com/">
```

and i still have Content Security Policy issue.

Only when i try

```
{ path: '', component: HomePageComponent },
```

application displays correctly.

My application localy working without problems but on Heroku when i try e.q  `https://myAngularApp.herokuapp.com/some-routing` i have this result in console

[image]

and on my site -> Not Found
[image]

What do I have to do for the heroku application to work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted all CSP-related files from index.html. I added a few changes to the server.js file and "Not Found" disappeared, but I ran into "Cannot GET / path" problem. I found the answer here [Angular 2: 404 error occur when I refresh through the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284988/angular-2-404-error-occur-when-i-refresh-through-the-browser)

Below I put the files that have been changed:

```
 "name": "surveyjs-angular-cli",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "postinstall": "ng build --aot",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
    },
```

`app.module`

```
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SurveyComponent,
    MyOtherComponents
    HomePageComponent,
  ],
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule, AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
  exports: [AppComponent, SurveyComponent, BrowserModule, FormsModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

`index.html`

```html
<html class="image">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/inexorabletash/polyfill/master/typedarray.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill@8/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

`server.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

// Serve only the static files form the dist directory
app.use(express.static('./dist'));

app.get('', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/', 'index.html'));
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/', 'index.html'));
});

// Start the app by listening on the default Heroku port
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8090);
```

The key was to add this:

```
providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
```

Credit to @granty for his contribution.

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax errors in the meta tag. All CSP directives be separated by semi-colon `;`. Also you missed a space in the `default-src*` that leads to  `default-src 'none'`. So your meta tag should looks like:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
    content="default-src * 'self';
       style-src 'unsafe-inline';
       script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://mySpringBootApp.herokuapp.com https://myAngularApp.herokuapp.com/">
```

BTW, `default-src * 'self'` could be replased with `default-src *` because `*` covers any host-sources including `'self'`.

Please note:

- using `'unsafe-inline'` in the `script-src` directive leads to CSP does not protect against XSS.
- `style-src 'unsafe-inline'` means you can't load external styles from you own domain via `<link href='your_domain.com/style.css' rel='stylesheet'>`. Maybe `style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'` is what you need there.

Comment: Thanks for yours answear, but it does't wokr for me :( this is my whole index.html file:
[link](https://pastebin.com/X6Ru27My).
I tried in different configurations, none of the tips work :( The main page is displayed and the component pages are not found

Comment: And my console after your hints: [link](https://ibb.co/KW5tGyy)

Comment: "Not found" is not a CSP related issue. Do remove CSP meta tag and check is your app works or not. If the app still not working check [related SO posts](https://www.google.ru/search?q=Angular+Heroku+page+not+found+site%3Astackoverflow.com&newwindow=1), because it's a config error.