# Angular 2 - 404 page not displaying

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes, angular2-routing

I have set up a "404 - page not found" page for when the user enters a url that dooesn't match any paths in my web app:

```
export const routerConfig: Routes = [
   {
      component: LandingPageComponent,
      path: "",
   },
   {
      component: ProfilePageComponent,
      path: "profile",
   },
   {
      component: NotFoundPageComponent,
      path: "**",
   },
];
```

However when I type in my app address and then an incorrect path (eg `http://localhost:3000/prcds`) it just displays :

```
Cannot GET /prcds
```

In a blank web page with an error in the console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

I have added `NotFoundPageModule` into `app.module` imports.

I used the "configuration" section from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html and copied how they did it into my project to set up the 404 not found page.

How do I get it to stop displaying that error and display my actual page that I made for 404 errors?

It displays the same page from my other question so there is a small chance, that it is related to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41390426/3935156):

**My Code:**

not found page file structure:

[image]

notfoundpage.component.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Title } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@Component({
   selector: "not-found-page",
   styleUrls: ["dist/app/components/not-found-page/not-found-page.component.css"],
   templateUrl: "dist/app/components/not-found-page/not-found-page.component.html",
})
export class NotFoundPageComponent {
   constructor(private titleService: Title) {
      this.titleService.setTitle("Not Found");
   }
}
```

notfoundpage.module.ts

```
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import * as NotFoundPage from "./index";

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      NotFoundPage.NotFoundPageComponent,
   ],
   exports: [NotFoundPage.NotFoundPageComponent],
   imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule],
})
export class NotFoundPageModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-reference
/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/moment/moment.d.ts" />

// Angular 2 modules
import { Component, NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import {
   ControlValueAccessor,
   FormBuilder,
   FormGroup,
   FormsModule,
   ReactiveFormsModule,
   Validators,
} from "@angular/forms";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { AgmCoreModule } from "angular2-google-maps/core";
import { routerConfig } from "../app.routes";

// Plugin modules
import { Ng2Bs3ModalModule } from "ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal";

// App modules
import { AboutPageModule } from "../components/about-page/about-page.module";
import { AddPageModule } from "../components/add-page/add-page.module";
import { FindPageModule } from "../components/find-page/find-page.module";
import { LandingPageModule } from "../components/landing-page/landing-page.module";
import { NotFoundPageModule } from "../components/not-found-page/not-found-page.module";
import { ProfilePageModule } from "../components/profile-page/profile-page.module";
import { RegisterPageModule } from "../components/register-page/register-page.module";
import { SharedModule } from "../components/shared/shared.module";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
   bootstrap: [AppComponent],
   declarations: [
      AppComponent,
   ],
   imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      RouterModule.forRoot(routerConfig),
      FormsModule,
      Ng2Bs3ModalModule,
      AgmCoreModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule,
      LandingPageModule,
      FindPageModule,
      AddPageModule,
      AboutPageModule,
      RegisterPageModule,
      ProfilePageModule,
      NotFoundPageModule,
      SharedModule,
   ],
   providers: [
      FormBuilder,
   ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

whole app.routes.ts:

```
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { AboutPageComponent } from "./components/about-page/about-page.component";
import { AddPageComponent } from "./components/add-page/add-page.component";
import { FindPageComponent } from "./components/find-page/find-page.component";
import { LandingPageComponent } from "./components/landing-page/landing-page.component";
import { NotFoundPageComponent } from "./components/not-found-page/not-found-page.component";
import { ProfilePageComponent } from "./components/profile-page/profile-page.component";
import { RegisterPageComponent } from "./components/register-page/register-page.component";

export const routerConfig: Routes = [
   {
      component: LandingPageComponent,
      path: "",
   },
   {
      path: "",
      pathMatch: "full",
      redirectTo: "",
   },
   {
      component: FindPageComponent,
      path: "find",
   },
   {
      component: AddPageComponent,
      path: "add",
   },
   {
      component: RegisterPageComponent,
      path: "register",
   },
   {
      component: AboutPageComponent,
      path: "about",
   },
   {
      component: ProfilePageComponent,
      path: "profile",
   },
   {
      path: "**",
      pathMatch: "full",
      redirectTo: "NotFoundPageComponent",
   },
   {
      component: ProfilePageComponent,
      path: "**",
   },
];
```

Comment: Replace `NotFoundPageComponent` with `ProfilePageComponent` and check if you type an incorrect path, it will redirect you into profile page then.

Comment: @K.Daniek It doesn't redirect to the profile page. Still just says cannot get

Comment: Give me whole code from your routing file with all imports, etc.

Comment: @K.Daniek Just added it to my question then. Cheers

Comment: Could you change   `templateUrl: "dist/app/components/not-found-page/not-found-page.component.html",`
to `templateUrl: "./not-found-page.component.html",` and I do not get it why it is `dist` not `src` ?

Comment: here is simple article to fix this issue https://blog.almightytricks.com/2020/10/14/how-to-fix-404-page-not-found-error-after-build-in-angular-or-react-or-vue-js/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your `app.routes.ts` file with following code:

```js
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { AboutPageComponent } from "./components/about-page/about-page.component";
import { AddPageComponent } from "./components/add-page/add-page.component";
import { FindPageComponent } from "./components/find-page/find-page.component";
import { LandingPageComponent } from "./components/landing-page/landing-page.component";
import { NotFoundPageComponent } from "./components/not-found-page/not-found-page.component";
import { ProfilePageComponent } from "./components/profile-page/profile-page.component";
import { RegisterPageComponent } from "./components/register-page/register-page.component";

const routerConfig: Routes = [
   {
      component: LandingPageComponent,
      path: "",
   },
   {
      component: FindPageComponent,
      path: "find",
   },
   {
      component: AddPageComponent,
      path: "add",
   },
   {
      component: RegisterPageComponent,
      path: "register",
   },
   {
      component: AboutPageComponent,
      path: "about",
   },
   {
      component: ProfilePageComponent,
      path: "profile",
   },
   {
      component: NotFoundPageComponent,
      path: "404",
   },
   {
      path: "**",
      redirectTo: '404' 
   }
];

export const routerConfig = RouterModule.forRoot(routerConfig);
```

Comment: If it still doesn't work, you should consider using `angular-cli`.

Comment: Your code has quite a few errors so im fixing them but changing the code quite a bit

Comment: Errors? You mean the last line? It comes from `angular-cli`. If it doesn't fit your code, just delete it and replace `const routerConfig: Routes = ...` with `export const routerConfig: Routes = ...` like it was before. But it's kinda strange that it routes to the `register` instead of `404`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give pathMatch: 'full', like below:

```
        export const routerConfig: Routes = [
           {
              component: LandingPageComponent,
              path: "",
           },
           {
              component: ProfilePageComponent,
              path: "profile",
           },
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'NotFoundPageComponent', pathMatch: 'full' },
           {
              component: NotFoundPageComponent,
              path: "**",
           },
        ];
```

In your "notfoundpage.module.ts", try below:

Replace this:

```
       import * as NotFoundPage from "./index";
```

With this:

```
        import {NotFoundPageComponent } from './not-found-page.component';
```

And replace this:

```
     declarations: [
          NotFoundPage.NotFoundPageComponent,
       ],
       exports: [NotFoundPage.NotFoundPageComponent]
```

With this:

```
         declarations: [
              NotFoundPageComponent,
           ],
           exports: [NotFoundPageComponent]
```