# Configure history.pushState for Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-cli

My Angular 2 application uses the default [HTML 5 `history.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries) [location strategy](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#browser-url-styles). How do I configure a server with `history.pushState` so browser refreshes and browser URLs do not generate `404`s?

For example, the [Tour of Heroes](http://embed.plnkr.co/71VEirn2WzveVVMuHGp5/) application has a few different application routes like:

```
http://localhost:8080/dashboard
http://localhost:8080/heroes
http://localhost:8080/detail/13
```

If you hit refresh on one of these routes, or type one of the URLs, you'll get `404` since `/detail/13` is an application route, not a server resource. I've configured the location strategy at the top of the `head` in my `index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="/">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tour of Heroes</title>
```

but how should a server be configured so it sends all URLs to my application instead of generating a `404`?

**Note**:
This question is the complement to the questions [Angular 2 : 404 error occur when i refresh through Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284988/angular-2-404-error-occur-when-i-refresh-through-browser) and [Angular 2.0 router not working on reloading the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser/31457808#31457808) asking **how** to address this problem. For Firebase, there's this: [When I refresh my website I get a 404. This is with Angular2 and firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34415725/when-i-refresh-my-website-i-get-a-404-this-is-with-angular2-and-firebase/) and for Apache there's this: [htaccess redirect for Angular routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739455/htaccess-redirect-for-angular-routes).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## nginx

To use [**nginx**](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/):

`/etc/nginx/ngin.conf`

```
location / {
    root   /home/jan/tour-of-heroes/;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}

error_page 404 =200 /index.html;
```

- supports `history.pushState`
- production HTTP server

## pushstate-server

To use [**pushstate-server**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pushstate-server):

```
pushstate-server /home/jan/tour-of-heroes
```

- supports `history.pushState`
- production HTTP server

## express

To use [**express**](https://expressjs.com/):

```
node express.js
```

where `express.js`:

```
var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    port = process.env.PORT || 8083,
    app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname ));

app.get('*', function(request, response){
  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port);
```

- supports `history.pushState`
- production HTTP server

## http-server

To use [**http-server**](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server):

```
node http-server/bin/http-server /home/jan/tour-of-heroes
```

- **no** `history.pushState`
- production HTTP server

## live-server

To use [**live-server**](https://github.com/tapio/live-server):

```
live-server --entry-file=index.html /home/jan/tour-of-heroes
```

- supports `history.pushState`
- *development* HTTP server

## ng serve

To use [**ng serve**](https://cli.angular.io/):

```
ng serve -prod
```

or with [ahead-of-time compilation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html):

```
ng serve -prod -aot
```

- supports `history.pushState`
- production application build
- *development* HTTP server

Answer (score 3):

Create your project using latest angular-cli version, they changed the build system between beta.10 and beta.14, from SystemJS to Webpack.

Use **LocationStrategy and HashLocationStrategy** class in your `app.module.ts` as shown in below code sample. It will solve your refresh issue on any particular route when you deploy your application to any http server like (nginx).

After adding these classes to providers section, run `ng serve` and your application root will look like `http://localhost:4200/#/` in browser.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [ 
    ...,
    {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

When you refresh, it will reload at it's proper place.

Also check [Angular 2.0 router not working on reloading the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser/31457808#31457808) for more info.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, @satendra, for pointing to that question. I'm using the default `PathLocationStrategy` which I'll clarify in my question.