# Direct loading routes in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I have an Angular application that navigates to two routes:

```
http://localhost:8080/ /* Landing page */
http://localhost:8080/details/:id /* Result page */
```

Whenever I navigate to, for example, `http://localhost:8080/details/4235`. I'm met with the error: *Cannot GET /details/4235*

Here is how I setup my routes, in my:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LandingPage } from './components/landingpage/landingpage.component';
import { ResultPage } from './components/resultpage/resultpage.component';

import { TitleService } from './services/title.service';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LandingPage },
  {
    path: 'details/:id', component: ResultPage, pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [TitleService]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Which I import into my:

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; // <-- NgModel lives here
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent }         from './app.component';
import { LandingPage } from './components/landingpage/landingpage.component';
import { ResultPage } from './components/resultpage/resultpage.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LandingPage,
    ResultPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule, // <-- import the FormsModule before binding with [(ngModel)]
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I'm having trouble finding a working Angular 2 method of dealing with direct-linking to a url.

How can I setup direct linking in Angular 2, so that when I load, say, http://localhost:8080/details/4235 it loads my `ResultPage` component.

**edit:**

Loading `http://localhost:8080/#/details/4235` , is valid, but it re-loads the LandingPage component. And I am trying to load the ResultPage component when there is an extended url.

Comment: I guess you are missing the `#` in it

Comment: try this:
http://localhost:8080/#/details/:id

Comment: @Aravind  . Thank you for the responses! When I try this URL, it loads the LandingPage component, but not the ResultPage component. I'm trying to get it to load the ResultPage.

Comment: you get any error?

Comment: no errors, it just loads my LandingPage

Comment: use `pathMatch: 'full'` against the route definition

Comment: I'll try it out, thank you! Sorry, I am new to angular.

Comment: @Aravind unfortunantly it still redirects to the landing page component. I have updated the original post with my changes. I think it might be because my LandingPage component path: ' ' intercepts everything.

Comment: can you post the resultpage component ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/vqk6SLAD here is the result page, sorry it's a bit messy @RahulSingh

Comment: the first thing is that why in the resultpage are you adding the service  

i:e  providers: [TaskService] and also you have to get the route details in ngOnInit where are you taking those details ?

Comment: I do 'providers: [TaskService]' in the resultpage, because when I remove it, I get the error " No provider for TaskService!". Should I be adding it elsewhere? By route details in the ngOnInit, do you mean the /:id? I use that id to query my service, which queries my backend api for information, which I use to display on the result page component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LandingPage } from 
'./components/landingpage/landingpage.component';
import { ResultPage } from 
'./components/resultpage/resultpage.component';

import { TitleService } from './services/title.service';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LandingPage },
{
path: 'details/:id', component: ResultPage
}
];

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule],
providers: [TitleService]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

here you're loading the empty path first. Then the other paths will load. Update the empty path route. Keep it at last in the hierarchy.

Updated Code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LandingPage } from ' 
./components/landingpage/landingpage.component';
import { ResultPage } from 
'./components/resultpage/resultpage.component';

import { TitleService } from './services/title.service';

const routes: Routes = [
{
path: 'details/:id', component: ResultPage
},
{ path: '', component: LandingPage } //<-- here  
];

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule],
providers: [TitleService]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

EDIT:
Also there might be problem that your browser doesn't support HTML5 pushState. I'm referring some SO links that might help out.

[Configure history.pushState for Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40142130/configure-history-pushstate-for-angular-2)

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284988/angular-2-404-error-occur-when-i-refresh-through-browser)

[Angular 2.0 router not working on reloading the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser/31457808#31457808)

Comment: Thank you for the response! Unfortunately, http://localhost:8080/#/details/246 , still re-directs to my landing page component after your change. http://localhost:8080/details/246 still returns Cannot GET /details/246

Comment: try to remove the empty path route then take a look at the error when trying localhost:8080/details/246.

Comment: I tried as you said, and there was no error except for the Cannot GET /details/246 . Here is an image of what occurs http://i.imgur.com/6LGTWbu.png  **note the header and footer on the left-side are loaded in my root component

Comment: The header and footer that you see on the left are from my root component, which loads on all components. The actual ResultPage never loads, it's just blank where the html should be

Comment: Try to navigate to the ResultPage by code. Like make a link and try to navigate by url there by using routerLink.
The problem may be you're trying to get there manually.
This sounds like your server doesn't support HTML5 pushState. You can try to switch to HashLocationStrategy which doesn't need server support.

try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861628/location-and-hashlocationstrategy-stopped-working-in-beta-16

Comment: "``` This sounds like your server doesn't support HTML5 pushState```" This was my issue. I was using express server, and I needed to include this https://pastebin.com/9iYbeEbM line at the bottom of my express routes. If you update your answer I will accept it. Thank you again!

Comment: finally we did it. 
;)