# server responded with a status of 404 - storage blob

Tags: angular, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, lighthouse

I'm unable to run a lighthouse report on my app due to a 404 error

[image]

When I look at the console I have a 404 error

[image]

I don't have this issue when running locally. Just in the cloud. The pages all load fine and I can navigate my app no problem, but that error popups up on every route I go in my app. 
I'm using azure storage blob to host my app and the document name and path is configured like this: 
[image]

I've been stuck on this for awhile so I appreciate any help!

Comment: are the routes getting formed on cloud correct, also as you have mentioned index.html as error document path, your storage serving index.html on 404?

Comment: I can go to /login or /listings by typing in address bar and it will take me to that route when index document name and error document path are set to index.html. If I set Error document path to 404.html, that's not the case. To be fair though, I don't see the 404.html file after running ng build in azure storage blob where static website files are or in dist folder from vscode. Here's how the folder structure looks like with 404.html file https://postimg.cc/BXJN7nm0

Comment: Maybe this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34415725/when-i-refresh-my-website-i-get-a-404-this-is-with-angular2-and-firebase/34416946#34416946

Comment: That didn't work, but I tried the answer below it https://stackoverflow.com/a/50607952/4350389 and that seemed to do the trick. Thanks for pointing that post out!

Comment: Typically light house request cannot perform such a request due to authentication checkpoints. because it required to be authenticate the request prior to send, which lighthouse dont do