# Error Handling in S3 bucket static hoisting and cloud front configuration

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, http-status-code-404, amazon-cloudfront, web-hosting

I have an angular application. I am hoisting it on the S3 bucket. I have specified the index and error document properly.

[image]

In the cloud front configurations, I have specified the error pages respectively.

[image]

My application is working error free, But I see the error printing in the browser console in production.

[image]

How do I resolve this ??? I am open to all solutions, Please guide me.

Comment: Possible dupicate of [404 error on reloading angular project when deployed on aws s3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63019400/2435473)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true }) in the app-routing module file. This will display a # in the route in the browser but resolved your issue.